# Overridden std::ostream flush() function not called by std::flush

Tags: c++, templates, stl, flush, ostream

I've overridden `std::ostream::flush()` function. Below I've removed all other code from the example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

class CMyStream : public std::streambuf, public std::ostream
{
    public:
        explicit CMyStream() throw() : std::ostream(this)
        {
            // Intentionally empty block
        }

        std::ostream &flush() 
        { 
            std::cout << "Overridden flush called\n"; 
            return (*this);
        }

        int sync()
        {
            std::cout << "Overridden sync called\n";
            return 0;   // Success
        }

};
```

I try to use it like this:

```
CMyStream myStream;
myStream << "Test" << std::flush;
```

, but the overridden `CMyStream::flush()` or `CMyStream::sync()` functions are not called by the `std::flush` manipulator. If I debug I see that the default `std::ostream::flush()` is called and not my overriden function.

Is there a way around this problem, or do I have to call `myStream.flush()` directly and not with the manipulator?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `std::ostream::flush` method is not virtual, so you cannot properly override it, and you should not. What you should do instead is to create your own buffer class inherited from `std::basic_streambuf` or `std::basic_filebuf` or `std::basic_stringbuf` and override protected `int sync()` method in there. Your stream class then should create proper buffer type in it's constructor.

Comment: It's worth noting that the result of `mystream << "Test"` is a reference to an ostream, not a reference to a CMyStream.  Hence the call directly to ostream's non-virtual flush method.

Comment: Adding `virtual` had no effect, I've updated the code with it.

Comment: @DaleWilson Ok? So how can I modify `mystream << "Test"` so that `CMyStream` is referenced and not std::ostream?

Comment: @DaleWilson No, don't take that route. Slava already told you what you should do instead.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen you cannot add virtual to `std::ostream::flush` method, adding virtual to your class method will do nothing. And again you should not do that, you suppose to implement that behavior in buffer.

Comment: @Slava I've alreddy overridden `std::streambuf` with my own buffer asf and it works fine, its calling `std::flush` manipulator I want to have work  I don't see the connection with `sync()` though.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen `std::ostream::flush()` calls `sync()` internally.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen   Sorry I did not mean to imply that `virtual` was a solution.   The decision to avoid `virtual` in iostreams was intentional.  Overriding std::ostream is not the way to change behavior.  The approach Slava described is the correct way to customize stream behavior.  I was just trying to explain the results you were seeing.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen `std::basic_ostream::flush` calls non virtual `std::basic_streambuf::pubsync` which calls protected virtual `std::basic_streambuf::sync`, so if you initialized your buffer properly it should work.

Comment: @Slava Adding `sync()` had no effect, see my updated example. I suspect @DaleWilson is onto something.

Comment: You should not add sync method to your stream class. You should create a new *streambuf* class and implement sync there. Streams and streambufs are different things. You should create *both*.

Comment: @n.m. Why not? I'm doing as above for ages and it works just fine.

Comment: Because, as you have just discovered, it doesn't work. Iostreams are built with some non-obvious design choices. You conform to them if your goal is working code. You may keep trying your old way if it makes you happy, just be aware that it won't work.

Comment: There is a [book](http://www.angelikalanger.com/IOStreams/contents.htm) about iostreams, you may want to consider reading it.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen "sync() had no effect" - you should read and understand the answer, placing sync() in your stream class simply shows you do not.